# Is there a library to handle form like in Google Contact

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In Google Contacts, by default the form displays the values with some

(read only) but when you click on a value, it converts the field into an  so you can edit it, and when you press enter, it updates the value, remove the  and redisplay the new value in the

.

So it's really easy to add/modify information in one click.

I'm looking for a lib that do that, ideally that handle the whole process javascript+ajax+ror. Or just the javascript+ajax, or just javascript at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think, like many of the other products, that they use GWT. Google Web Toolkit, its actually written in Java then cross compiled into Javascript.  It allows them to write sourcecode for both the front and backend in Java and then creates optimised javascript for cross browsers.

The advantage of this is it is all widget based, and its super easy to switch components in and out without having to manually interact with the DOM.

However, if you do not wish to go down this route you can do it very simply in javascript using ajax calls.  On a blur event you make an ajax call to your server which saves the field. On success it switches back to a Label.  When you click on the label/text it switches for a textedit and uses the same contents as the label.  No real need to use a plugin for this kind of thing as its actually pretty basic, it just looks good :).